# "Also create xib file" button disabled

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, xib

I have this problem with creating `UIView's` subclasses. Creating, for example, `UIViewControllers` or `UITableViewCells` is okay.

Why this happens?

[image: UIView button disabled]
[image: UIViewController is okay]

I create view using `cmd+N` and Xcode Version 7.3.1:[image: new file]

Comment: I see solutions, but nobody has actually answered the question: why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add custom Xcode template that will fix this issue or add an existing template. Read more how to create and add it to Xcode [here](https://medium.com/@dima.cheverda/xcode-9-templates-596e2ed85609).

Template can be found [here](https://github.com/dimacheverda/XcodeUIViewTemplate).

Answer (score 9):

Create the View and the Cocoa Touch Class separately, but with the same name, then set the Class of the xib to the name of the file.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Yes as per @PRECover, the xib check mark button is disabled always
to help you more I am describing the steps to make it easy for you

Step - 1 : Create the UIView class without the xib.
Step - 2 : Go to create a new File and choose the Resource template this time 
[image: See the screen shots below for step - 2 and so on]

[image: Next Step]

[image: Next step]

Step 4 - Now go to to the view class and write the "getView" function

```
class SampleView: UIView {

/*
// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    // Drawing code
}
*/

func getView() -> UIView {
    return NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("SampleView", owner: nil, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
}
}
```

[image: Now go to to the view class and write the "getView" function]

Step 5 - Write the method below and call that to add the view in the main View (where ever you want)

```
    func designSampleView()
{
    let sview = (SampleView()).getView();
    NSLog("Test ", "");
    self.view.addSubview(sview);
}
```