# Why when create new UIView class, can't create a XIB together?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, xib

If I create a new UIViewController class, I could also checked the box to `Also create XIB file`.

However, why when I create UIView, the check box is disabled, and I have to manually create a XIB to link the two (XIB and the UIView) together?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39105607/also-create-xib-file-button-disabled

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> If I create a new UIViewController class, I could also checked the box to Also create XIB file. However, **why** when I create UIView, the check box is disabled, and I have to manually create a XIB to link the two (XIB and the UIView) together? [Emphasis mine.]

Because the relationship between a view controller and a nib is totally different from the relationship between a view and a nib. UIView and nibs do not "go together" in any magic or important way, as do a UIViewController and its view nib.

- With a view controller, if there is a nib with the same name as the view controller class, and if the File's Owner in that nib is typed as the class of the view controller, and if the `view` outlet of the File's Owner is pointed at the top-level UIView in the nib, the view controller can load its view automatically from the nib. That is a complicated arrangement, and it is doubtful that you would know how to configure it correctly (and it's a lot of work even if you do know how), so the template offers to configure it for you. This is a standard, important, automatic relationship.
- But with a view and a nib there is *no* such standard automatic relationship, and there is no complexity. If you want a certain view in a certain nib to be of a certain UIView subclass, you just say so in its Identity inspector, and kaboom you're done. So just do that and move on.